# What is it? Access denied for user 'fonok@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Tags: php, html, mysql

What should I do to be good?
Im a new programmer and i dont know what is the problem... I have a localhost Wampp server and in the folder 1 php, 1 html and 2 sql code.
My Php code:

```
<?php
  require_once("config.php");

  $dbc = mysqli_connect("localhost","fonok","12345","elvis_store")
    or die('Error connecting to MySQL server.');

  $first_name = $_POST['firstname'];
  $last_name = $_POST['lastname'];
  $email = $_POST['email'];

  $query = "INSERT INTO email_list (first_name, last_name, email)  VALUES ('$first_name', '$last_name', '$email')";
  mysqli_query($dbc, $query)
    or die('Error querying database.');

  echo 'Customer added.';

  mysqli_close($dbc);
?>
```

**SQL:**

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'fonok'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '12345' WITH GRANT OPTION

CREATE DATABASE elvis_store
USE elvis_store

CREATE TABLE email_list
(
    first_name VARCHAR(20),
    last_name VARCHAR(20),
    email VARCHAR(60)
)
```

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. http://bobby-tables.com/. Also, is there a reason you're using **mysqli_** instead of **PDO**?

Answer (score 0):

To Make sure your PRIVILEGES,

SQL:

```
 SHOW GRANTS FOR 'fonok'@'localhost';
```

Once you have finalized the permissions that you want to set up for your new users, always be sure to reload all the privileges.

`FLUSH PRIVILEGES;`

Your changes will now be in effect.

Ref:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-create-a-new-user-and-grant-permissions-in-mysql

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/adding-users.html

Answer (score 0):

Edit your phpmyadmin config.inc.php file :
answer 1

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = '**your-root-username**';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '**root-password**';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;
```

answer 2 login with root password and use

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'fonok'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '12345' WITH GRANT OPTION
```

then use script